# MongoDB find database storage

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

Hey guys I am using [this bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) for `symfony` and `mongodb`.

When I do this :

> `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle`

I have this :

```
Generating documents for "AppBundle"
> generating AppBundle\Document\MessageUser
```

And for this :

> `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update`

I have this :

```
Updated indexes for all classes
```

So as you can see i have 0 error but I don't see the database or the collections with the command "mongo" (and show bds, use , show collections ...)

So where can I see where is save the document ? Or can I fix this ?(all works fine for me in local but I have this when I put to server)

Comment: Such a nice edit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use:

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:create

in order to create the database and then:

> php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update

to create the collections.

Comment: ok that's generate the database but when i do : $dm->getRepository('AppBundle:MessageUser')->findAll()); i have an 500 error (thats works on local but on server not so i can't have detail error ....)

Comment: This is a different issue and should be answered in a different question. Your question was about the generation of the database and I answered it